# Difference between “They are goofing” and “They are goofing off”?

Tags: meaning, slang

What's the difference between "They are goofing" and "They are goofing off"? I have heard both, but I don't know the distinction.

Comment: Be aware that the word "goofing" is primarily US / North American English slang and is very informal (i.e. don't write it in formal emails).

Comment: I do not know what *goofing* means without the *off* after it.  It is not grammatical to me.

Comment: @tchrist: Perhaps it's uncommon, but you can find it [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=fZZ4QKZEumIC&pg=PA232&lpg=PA232&dq=%22he+was+goofing%22+-off+-around&source=bl&ots=NWZAUVMzUN&sig=H6U6NNG4MhoXmFCLIsRX3Y8LGW8&hl=en&sa=X&ei=-GwhUc_FOcrvrQH-l4GIBw&ved=0CFQQ6AEwCA#v=onepage&q=%22he%20was%20goofing%22%20-off%20-around&f=false) and [there](http://books.google.com/books?id=x67UyUnHXYkC&pg=PA79&lpg=PA79&dq=%22my+friend+was+goofing+at+a+table%22&source=bl&ots=cJdGFaWG7c&sig=r9OFJksQxfF04J12oqxb1OXHMqM&hl=en&sa=X&ei=G24hUaaYDMTf2QXmnYDAAg&ved=0CC0Q6AEwAA).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think sometimes they can be used interchangeably, at least informally.

The verb *goof* has several meanings, none of which are particularly flattering. It can mean:

- to make a blunder (as in, *"Oops! I goofed..."*, also sometimes called *goofing **up***),
- to joke around with in a teasing way (as in, *"I'm just goofing with you..."*, also sometimes called *goofing **on***, or *goofing **around with***),
- or to waste time idly (as in, *"We were just goofing at the mall"*, also sometimes called *goofing **around***, or *goofing **off***).

According to many [dictionaries](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/goof-off), the phrasal verb *goofing off* adds to a measure of irresponsibility to the simple act of *fooling around* – it implies loafing, particularly when one should have been doing something else. However, I'm not convinced most native speakers give much thought to that subtle distinction very often.

According to strict dictionary defintions, then, a group of teenagers hanging around on their skateboards on a Friday afternoon might be said to be *goofing* or *goofing around*. However, on a Thursday evening, that same group of teenagers might be said to be *goofing off* (assuming there's unfinished homework due on Friday).

Here's an [Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=goofing%20off,goofing%20around,goofing,%28goofing%20around%20%2b%20goofing%20off%20%2b%20goofing%20up%20%2b%20goofing%20on%29&year_start=1940&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) you might find interesting:

[image]

As you can see, there's not much distance between the green line and the gold line, showing that, more often than not, the word *goofing* is used with another word, as in the expressions *goofing off* or *goofing around*.

Answer (score 1):

As verb, *goof* means "spend time idly or foolishly; fool around"; *goof off* means "evade a duty; idle or shirk."

> I was goofing around and broke my arm.

> She was goofing off from her math homework.

Comment: No, *to goof* is to make an error: “He goofed” means that he made a mistake.

Comment: Isn't that _goof up_?

Comment: Same thing, yeah.

Comment: Where I live, kiamlaluno is quite right.

Yes, "goofing off" is always avoiding what you're supposed to be doing but straight "goof" or "goofing" has two very different meanings.

kiamlaluno's "I was goofing…" meaning "fooling…" is one, often expressed as "goofing around."

tchrist's “He goofed” meaning "made a mistake" is the other, often given as "goofing up."